# How to make my A4 print preview handle dynamic content in Laravel blade?

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-blade

my task is to create a print preview page (which kinda resembles opening an A4 document in Microsoft word) and then turn that page into pdf using browsershot.

I'm stuck with making my preview page handle dynamic content ('if content exceeds A4 size, excess text should automatically move to a new A4 page'). Any advice on how I can achieve this? thank you

My print-preview blade file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>A4 Print Preview</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
        <style>
            /* * {
                outline: 1px solid blue;
            } */
            body {
                background: rgb(204, 204, 204);

            }
            div.page {
                background: white;
                width: 21cm;
                height: 29.7cm;
                display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;
                margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
                padding: 1.27cm 2.54cm 1.27cm 2.54cm;
                box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
                background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%), linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(240, 40, 40, 1) 0%, rgba(240, 40, 40, 1) 100%);
                background-clip: content-box, padding-box;
                /* overflow:hidden; */

            }
            @media print {
                body,
                div.page[data-size="A4"] {
                    margin: 0;
                    box-shadow: 0;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- should automatically move excess content to a new A4 page -->
        <div class="page" data-size="A4">
            <main class="flex flex-col text-left">
                <h2 class="font-bold mt-16">MISSION AND VISION OF THE PDO</h2>
                <p class="mt-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sagittis id consectetur purus ut. Massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor magna. Tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi. Interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper. Ornare arcu odio ut sem. Tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc. Ut tristique et egestas quis. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis. Mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat. Ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor urna. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu. Commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Libero justo laoreet sit amet cursus. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam. Feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu.

                    Mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id. Pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies. Vulputate odio ut enim blandit. Ipsum a arcu cursus vitae. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Quis varius quam quisque id diam. Sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus. Sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat. Nam libero justo laoreet sit. Condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique.
                    
                    Feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu. Nam libero justo laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum. Faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas. Faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi. Scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu. Magna sit amet purus gravida quis blandit turpis cursus in. Aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit. Neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus. Nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet. Non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum. Semper eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque. Sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium. In vitae turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci.
                    
                    Eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi. Ornare arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra. Turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed. Varius duis at consectetur lorem donec massa sapien. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu. Quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque. Id venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi. Enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt. Tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor. Sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum. Odio aenean sed adipiscing diam donec. Augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci. Ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium. Augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna et. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam.
                    
                    Sit amet justo donec enim diam. Mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor. Egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut. Mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar proin gravida. Sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et. Congue quisque egestas diam in. Imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum. A erat nam at lectus urna. Est sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis. Consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit amet cursus. Quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in. Massa tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium. Mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget. Massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit. Tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula. Urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed. Aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Et molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit.
                    
                    Tempus urna et pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies mi. Ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut tristique. Lacinia quis vel eros donec ac odio tempor orci dapibus. In arcu cursus euismod quis. Semper auctor neque vitae tempus. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis. Pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor. Ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat. Diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam. In metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet. Viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim. Scelerisque in dictum non consectetur. At augue eget arcu dictum varius duis. Eu ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum. Diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam. Elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim. Viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est. Ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat.
                    
                    Pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus. Semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam. Leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam. Semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam. Turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas. Viverra vitae congue eu consequat. Gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim. Turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue quisque. Dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat. Cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. Sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget. Tortor posuere ac ut consequat. Augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus. Aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris.
                    
                    Dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer vitae. Felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus. Proin gravida hendrerit lectus a. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet eget. Sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus. Enim tortor at auctor urna. Quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. In vitae turpis massa sed elementum. Eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis. Integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate. Enim nec dui nunc mattis enim ut. Nunc sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac. Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada. Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut. Cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero. Etiam tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Id eu nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus. Sit amet est placerat in egestas erat.
                    
                    In ante metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus. Leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget. Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget. Nam libero justo laoreet sit. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc. Sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper. Urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris. Volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in. Commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique. Quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in ante. Elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget. Commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue mauris. Ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim. Pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id. Elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus.
                    
                    Congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam maecenas. Sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis. Urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida. A diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl. Magna sit amet purus gravida quis blandit turpis cursus in. Mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est. Mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin. Lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque. Vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor. Nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat. Vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra.S</p>
                <h2 class="font-bold mt-5">BRIEF HISTORY OF THE PDO</h2>
                <p class="mt-5">In ante metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus. Leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget. Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget. Nam libero justo laoreet sit. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc. Sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper. Urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris. Volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in. Commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing. Aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique. Quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in ante. Elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget. Commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue mauris. Ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim. Pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id. Elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus.</p>
            </main>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image]